# Malicious links in SO Triage tests cleanup and origination

Tags: discussion, triage, external-links

I was reviewing posts, and received the following as a test (unsure if link is specific to me): https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/15049398

While it's obviously spam, it contains a link which could take a user to a malicious site. While it's unreasonable to expect link on SO to be clean, it would seem that **this post now originates not from the original poster, but from SO itself**. This is fully intentional as the system appears to only bring in very good or obviously spam posts as tests. So users are being provided with known-bad links by the SO Triage system.

This brings me to a question: *is any effort made to ensure links in SO Triage tests are safe?*

To which the answer is "no." as external links cannot be truly secured.

What, if anything should be done about this?

Possibilities

- this is fine
- don't include spam links (may nullify tests)
- buy up domains and don't list them (expensive)
- partner with another service who has a huge number of domains to set up fake spam links

Answer (score 15):

Your primary purpose as a reviewer is to recognize and handle inappropriate content.  If seeing inappropriate content is entirely unacceptable to you *then you shouldn't be reviewing*.  Part of your job is to recognize spam, and flag it accordingly.  That means seeing spam.  It's a part of the job you signed up for when you went to the queue (along with almost all of the other review queues as well).

Comment: I agree - but that's not what I was intending to refute/discuss - this is the distinction between SO providing spam and malicious links and those provided by a user.

Comment: @ti7 These links are provided by a user.  These audits are real posts, that a real spammer actually posted.  In the case of audits, a mod already found and deleted the spam, but it was shown to a reviewer to make sure they realize that they should have flagged it, had they seen it before the mod did so.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. However, the system (knowing that the post has spam content) is now re-providing it to triage reviewers. This is fully intentional as the system appears to only bring in very good or obviously spam posts as tests.

Comment: @ti7 Indeed.  That's the point of the audit; to show you known-bad content and to make sure you correctly identify it as bad content.  We know that it's okay to occasionally show you bad content because when you went to the review queue *you specifically signed up to identify bad content*, therefore hiding bad content from you is both unnecessary and counterproductive.

Comment: @ti7 Well, the system doesn't know whether or not a post that is deleted as spam/rude/abusive contains malicious links. It only knows that the post is spam/rude/abusive.

Comment: @dorukayhan Presumably the feature is to replace all links (in these audits of known-bad posts), not just those that are "malicious".

Comment: hmm.. I had meant this as a discussion, but my real topic appears to be being overlooked. I have edited my question to better highlight the topic.

Comment: @ti7 If you think that any posts that you see in /review are all good posts and there isn't any bad content and all links are 100% safe **then you need to stop reviewing now**.  Clearly you don't know what the system is, how it works, or how to use it.  Ensuring that audits don't contain bad content would mean that *wouldn't be doing their job*.  That they contain bad content *is their purpose*.  All that said, the posts are not "from SO itself".  They will appear to be posted by a new 1 rep user.  I don't even know what "from SO itself" would mean.  There is no such thing as a post "from SO".

Comment: I am deeply troubled that this was the interpretation of my post. Obviously; most posts in /review are straight out of the Eternal September *or they wouldn't be there*. I am not worried that links are malicious, only curious if there was any thoughts **on the subject of SO regurgitating them**. If I tell a story (original user) and a listener re-tells the story later (SO), they become the new provider of it and the steward of its contents, not I (original user).

Comment: @ti7 So you understand that there are going to be really bad posts in /review, and you know why they're there, but you think that we shouldn't be showing any bad posts there because then "SO would be sharing bad posts and that's wrong"?  That makes no sense.  Obviously there need to be bad posts shown in /review *because the purpose of /review is to show the reviewers bad or potentially bad posts*.  For SO to *not* show those posts in /review would mean that *those posts aren't getting reviewed* (or not reviewed as quickly/well) which would be *far* worse than some reviewers seeing them first.

Comment: @Servy, 1. I can't see any logic in your arguments as I see way more (3-4 times more) spam in the form of SO test questions than actual user posted spam. This is the 2nd malicious link that I have seen (looked to me as blatant self promotion) and it is from a test question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17992069). The other malicious link was a real question BUT someone else already added a comment to warn people. In summary: SO seems to do a much better job of spreading malware than an average malicious poster, as with poster only ~5 people will ever see a bad post.

Comment: @Alex Again, the content is being shown to people *who are there to judge whether or not the content is bad and to clean up bad content*.  If you're going to review bad content only to start randomly clicking on links and downloading things that you don't possibly think could be harmful then 1. you shouldn't be on the internet at all and 2. you shouldn't be reviewing posts in the first place, and if the audits end up kicking you out of the system they're doing their job.

Comment: All that said, the reason you see so little inappropriate content outside audits is *because systems like these do such a good job of getting rid of bad content*.  If systems like these didn't exist to remove the bad content then the site would be flooded with this bad content.

Comment: @Servy, RE: "If you're going to review bad content only to start randomly clicking on links and downloading things that you don't possibly think could be harmful ..." - I like how you changed direction into a personal attack in one sentence. 1. Should people like you be on SO? 2. The reason you see so little inappropriate content is because of people reviewing it - one would think. And **the system** is merely there to enable it. Surely spreading malicious content, that people "are not supposed to click on" is not its goal?

Comment: @Alex How is that a personal attack?  You think that if you're going to go out of your way to find and remove the inappropriate content on the site that you should never ever see anything inappropriate.  That's just not the case.  The whole *point* of the review queues is to find and handle inappropriate content.  If you can't handle seeing it, that's fine, many people can't, and there's nothing wrong with that, just don't use the review system and let other people handle cleaning it up.

Comment: That you think people willing to find and remove bad content from the site don't belong here doesn't make much sense...that is unless you have a problem with the type of person who'd find and remove inappropriate content, rather than being someone who wants inappropriate content to actually be properly handled by the system.

Comment: @Servy, here we go again, you shifted the topic again, this time to general discussion about review queues. The OPs question and my point is that bad content created by malicious people in review queues is not a problem (really, it is not!), rather, the problem is with SO itself promulgating the bad content in test questions, which in the end only helps spammers. To rephrase my original comment: SO [test questions] seems to do a much better job of spreading malware than an average malicious poster, as only ~5 people will ever see a malicious post. How many will see a malicious test question?

Comment: "That you think people willing to find and remove bad content from the site don't belong here ..." - I only have a problem with people who think that  "start randomly clicking on links" and "you shouldn't be on the internet at all" are valid argument points in a civil discussion. I assumed that there is an SO policy about not going personal and abusive, hence my point 1 - "should you be on SO".

Comment: @Alex So you don't have a problem with bad content being reviewed, you just have a problem with reviewers being tested to make sure they're actually doing their job properly, which means that you think it's perfectly acceptable for there to be lots of bad reviewers out there not actually reviewing properly (because that's what happens when we don't have audits ensuring people actually mark spam as spam).

Comment: You think it's abusive to say that someone that isn't capable of identifying spam or malicious content doesn't belong here?  How is that abusive?  It's for their own safety.  They're just going to hurt themselves or others if they're not capable of using the internet safely.  You're the one saying that I don't belong here at all just for saying that people that are too sensitive to ever see any spam shouldn't sign up to search through the worst content on the site trying to identify spam.  That's not abusive, that's just common sense.

Comment: You really like changing the subject, don't you? I will repeat my comment/question for the 3rd time, since you missed it twice before. Can you answer this: "To rephrase my original comment: SO [test questions] seems to do a much better job of spreading malware than an average malicious poster, as only ~5 people will ever see a malicious post. How many will see a malicious test question?"

Comment: @Alex How many will see the audit?  A handful.  5, maybe.  How many views will a page that the average spam post is posted to?  Do you think it's more or less than 5?  Do you think that removing the tools for proper management and removal of spam posts increases or decreases the amount of spam in the system, given that you're pro-spam-removal-tools?  Why do you think that having systems in place to find and remove bad content results in more people seeing bad content than doing nothing and letting the site be overrun with spam and other inappropriate content?

Comment: @Servy, why is it all black and white to you? Why not consider changing the tools to sanitise known malicious links from test questions? I would also dispute your claim that only 5 people will see an audit question (on common sense grounds; SO has quite a lot of people reviewing content, although only a handful of people do it every day ).

Comment: @Alex If you remove the inappropriate content from the post then *the post no longer contains inappropriate content* and a reviewer may well *correctly* pass it, as all inappropriate content has been sanitized from it.  Yes, there are lots of people that review content, but there are also lots of posts that get reviewed.  Each individual audit question only gets seen by a handful of people.  It's not like every single reviewer reviews the same audit every single time.